# table row is coming in wrap content in my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-xml

This is my layout and i want to add table row in to table layout by coding.

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgblack"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bgblack"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:background="@color/Grey"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/section_phone"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_phone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section_phone" >
                <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_phone"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**tablerow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_phone_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_phone_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_contact_call"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

but when i see output table row is not coming in full width. it is coming with only wrap content.

**Output**

[image: Output of layout with half]

So can you help me to make output in full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stretching selected column will fix your problem. See this link. [TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3astretchColumns)

```
<!-- The zero-based index of the columns to stretch. -->
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_phone"
        android:stretchColumns="0"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: thanks alot Shaiful... this is exactly what i want. Its works fine.